# jquery setting padding of siblings when a case is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i asked this question yesterday, and people were able to help me. However unfortunately it only answered part of my question.

Im trying to write jquery code that will detect for every class `product-price` if it has a sibling called `product-options`, and if it does check whether it has two or more dropdowns. If it has 2 of more dropdowns, then set the padding-top of its sibling `product price` to 35px. So if there is no dropdown OR only one then don't do anything to its sibling `product-price`.

```
<div class="product-container">
   <div class="product-price">Price info</div>
</div>

<div class="product-container">
   <div class="product-price">Price info</div>
   <div class="product-options">
      <select id="selectoptions1" name="product1" class="attribute_list">
         <option value="Colour (please select)">Colour (please select)</option>
         <option value="White">White</option>
         <option value="Navy Blue">Navy Blue</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product-container">
   <div class="product-price">Price info</div>
   <div class="product-options">
      <select id="selectoptions1" name="product1" class="attribute_list">
         <option value="Colour (please select)">Colour (please select)</option>
         <option value="White">White</option>
         <option value="Navy Blue">Navy Blue</option>
      </select>
      <select id="selectoptions2" name="product2" class="attribute_list">
         <option value="Small>Small</option>
         <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
         <option value="Large">Large</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product-container">
   <div class="product-price">Price info</div>
</div>
```

Anyone got any ideas?

BTW this is not the actual code, its part of it...to simplify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".product-price").each(function(){
  if ($(this).next(".production-options").children("select").length >= 2) {
    //Do your thing here
  }
});
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/xM7By/)

Comment: ok in my case, before the select dropdowns appear there are 4 more parent div classes/spans before they appear (necessary for bootstrap, and fluid). So the "select" are not direct children of product-options

Comment: they are however descendants

Comment: Use `.find` instead of `.children` then.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".product-price" ).each(function() {
        if($(this).siblings('.product-options').children('select').length >= 2) {
            $(this).css('padding-top', '35px');
        }
    });
});
```

[**Working jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JF9Xg/)